# how to refresh datatables after ajax response

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a problem, here I automatically click the button when reloading the page and send ajax, after being able to respond it will create datatables.
the problem is when the user clicks the get data button again, there is an error `DataTables warning: table id = tAccount - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`
this my script

```
 setTimeout(function() {
        $("#get_data").trigger('click');
    },10);

$("#get_data").click(function(){
    var url = "{{route('get-some-data')}}"
    // $('#getData').DataTable().clear().destroy();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: url, 
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Has been Updated',
                text: data.message.id,
            }).then(function() {
                var VendorClient = $("#tAccount").DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: false,
                ajax: "{{route('some-url-response')}}",
                columns: [
                {
                    data: "fullname",
                    name: "fullname",
                    orderable:false
                },
                {
                    data: "name",
                    name: "name",
                    orderable:false
                },
                {
                    data: "month",
                    name: "month",
                    orderable:false
                }
                ]
            });
            });  
            }
        });
});
```

the time of the first click when reloading the datatables page appears successfully, but when the second click after the datatables is created, it results an error

Comment: Can you move the declaration for var VendorClient  to top and in the place of your commented code  // $('#getData').DataTable().clear().destroy(); you try VendorClient.destroy();

Comment: I don't think I can move it sir, because before bringing up the datatables, there is a process of updating  data from  API on route {{route ('get-some-data')}}

Comment: @dev if I move to up, the datatables will bring up the data in the database before the data is updated

Comment: Okay..Might be you are correct but  Did you tried it? as I just wanted you to declare the variable at top var VendorClient; which will not have data and once your API call will be success then only you will have data.

Comment: I have added, and now try with VendorClient.ajax.reload (null, false); , but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery Ajax to populate your DataTable, why don't you use the built-in Ajax function? It's a lot simpler. [Follow this example to define your DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html), then when you want to reload inside your button click handler do:

```
VendorClient.ajax.reload();
```

Or if you want to change the url or search parameters do:

```
VendorClient.ajax.url('new-url-here').load();
```

If you have options that you want to send with your ajax url you can [define it as an object](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html).

By doing it this way you don't have the problems of recreating your DataTable each time.